# Checking with blank values not working as desired

Tags: php

I have written the below code i.e.

```
foreach($mainStockDetailsRows as $mainStockDetailsRow)
    {
        $sumQuantity = '';
        if(count($attrStocks["$mainStockDetailsRow->id_product"]) > 0)
        {
            $sumQuantity = array_sum($attrStocks["$mainStockDetailsRow->id_product"]);  
        }else{
            $sumQuantity = 0;
        }
        //$sumQuantity = trim($sumQuantity);
        
        if(($sumQuantity >= 0) && ($sumQuantity != ''))
        {
            $return .= 'somevalue';
            $return .= ";\n";   
        }
        
    }
```

Here the condition `if(($sumQuantity >= 0) && ($sumQuantity != ''))` does not work at all until in use trim of the value. I am not getting what wrong i have done in this code. Is there any mistake in the code? Even though the $sumQuantity value is 0, Its not coming inside the if condition.

--- Answer --

I got my answer in https://www.php.net/types.comparisons

Lesson learnt: Be careful with comparisons.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if(count($attrStocks["$mainStockDetailsRow->id_product"]) > 0)
```

to

```
if(count($attrStocks[$mainStockDetailsRow->id_product]) > 0)
```

And Here :

```
$sumQuantity = array_sum($attrStocks[$mainStockDetailsRow->id_product]);
```

**Remove double quotes**...Then it will work.You are not going to the first `if condition` itself so you are not getting `$sumQuantity` value properly.

Comment: Those things are working file. checking point i.e. ($sumQuantity != '') is not working.

Comment: echo $sumQuantity before the second if condition and tell me

Comment: $sumQuantity is giving value as 0

Comment: @Hacker `$sumQuantity` is always a number, either `0` or the number returned by `array_sum`.

Comment: Yes but its also not equal to '' right ? so why is it not coming inside IF loop ?